# parse a csv column into ndarray in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-processing

Currently I have a file called somefile.csv. And in this somefile.csv, there is a column with dtype of object looks like this:
[image]
Each row of this column contains 50 floats, e.g.:[-0.15 0.27 0.40, ...].

Is there any ways to parse this column into a 2d ndarray that looks like
[[-0.15, 0.27, 0.40, ...], [second row], [third row], ...]

Thank you!

Comment: Try `df[["vector_tweet"]].values`

Comment: `np.asarray(list(vectortweet))`

Comment: What you want to do is called transposing. You can simply do `vectortweet.transpose()`, assuming vectortweet is a Numpy array.

Comment: The column may be `object` dtype, but the elements are strings, the `str` of an array, not an array.